# Slide - Scroll To - gallery displaying images page - centered

Tags: jquery

I am searching for a "scroll to" effect like this one:

http://studio8169.com/?page_id=11

I used some code from this page:

http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-tutorials/create-a-horizontal-scrolling-website.html

Now my divs are on the left border of the browser. How can I get this to scroll in the center of the divs?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect answers like this here on SO. But I created something similar recently, so I'm just sharing.

Basically what you need is this:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uxuhut/2/)*

**[edit / download](http://jsbin.com/uxuhut/2/edit#javascript,html,live)**

```
  <div id="mid"> (Position: absolute, width:100%, height:400px; overflow:hidden;)
    
    <div id="gallery"> (position:relative;width:960px;margin:0 auto;)
       <div id="slider"> (position absolute;left:0px;width:100000px;height:400px;)
          <div class="box"></div> (position:relative; float:left;) width:960px;height:400px;
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
       <div class="btn btn_left"></div> (position:absolute;top:150px;left:0px;)
       <div class="btn btn_right"></div> (position:absolute;top:150px;right:0px;)
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

P.S. put the styles in a proper .css file or inside `<style>` tags

And just this little of javascript/jQuery I created:

```
var animateTime = 1000; // set preferred animation time
var galW = $('#gallery').innerWidth(); // return 960px
var slidesN = $('#slider>div.box').length;
var c = 0; // set counter to '0'

function states(){
  var cStat=c===-1?c=slidesN-1:c=c%slidesN; // counter states
  var btnStat=c===0?$('.btn_left').hide():$('.btn_left').stop(1).fadeIn(300); // left button states
}
states(); // set states at DOM ready

function anim(){
  $('#slider').stop(1).animate({left: -(c*galW)}, animateTime);
}

$('#gallery .btn').on('click',function(){
  var btnClass=$(this).hasClass('btn_left') ? c-- : c++ ;
  states();
  anim();
});
```

Comment: Hey roko you are a great person :-) that is it :-)

Comment: @user1383911 I forgot to add the `overflow:hidden` to the `#mid` element. Not is fixed. Happy coding! use it at wish! :)

Comment: hey roko thank you for your help. I have on question.  how i spring for example from box 2 to 5? i want make links under the box for the users. That the users can spring between the different boxs. For example the site -  http://studio8169.com/?page_id=11 - have buttons under the boxes!